# Error establishing a database connection in wordpress site , website not opening

Tags: database, errors

i had my website using wordpress in cpanel with PHP 7.4 version ,
mysql 5.6.41-84.1 version , i got Error establishing a database connection
tried enable

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

got
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password] in /home/user/public_html/abc/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1612

Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in /home/user/public_html/abc/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1612

Warning: mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password] in /home/user/public_html/abc/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1643

Warning: mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in /home/user/public_html/abc/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1643
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

any clues to resolve this issue

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like something's incompatible between your mysql server and your mysql client drivers in PHP. Is your server running on the same VPS or is it hosted elsewhere? Are the client drivers the same version as the server? Is this really mariadb not mysql? Can you connect to the database using the `mysql` command line tool on your server or does that fail with the same error?

Comment: these look like server/database issues rather than issues with WordPress itself